# Refresh View on changes in angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, observable, google-cloud-firestore

I have a component that load data from angular Firestore which has location in Geopoint. Am using AGM to geocode the latitude and longitude into a formatted address which is done after it has loaded all the data.
I would like to display the data with the address.

My `ts` code.

```
address: any;

    constructor(private mapsAPILoader: MapsAPILoader) {}

    ngOnChanges() {
        this.address
        console.log('on changes==>', this.address)
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.route.params.forEach((urlParameters) => {
            this.myId = urlParameters['Id'];
            console.log("contractor Id", this.contractorId)
        })

        this.afs.collection('mycolection').doc(this.myId).ref.get().then(result => {
            if (result.exists) {
                this.selectedC.push(result.data());
                console.log('this is some location', result.data())
            }
        }).then(() => {
            // console.log("contractor data", this.selectedContractor[0].location);
            let myLocation = this.selectedContractor[0].location;
            console.log('My location', myLocation)
            let res = {
                coords: {
                    latitude: myLocation._lat,
                    longitude: myLocation._long
                }
            }
            this.codeLatLng(res.coords);
        }).catch(error => {
            console.log(error.message)
        })
    }    
    codeLatLng(coords) {
        return this.mapsAPILoader.load().then(() => {
            let latlng = new google.maps.LatLng({ lat: coords.latitude, lng: coords.longitude });
            new google.maps.Geocoder().geocode({ 'location': latlng }, function (results, status) {
                console.log(status);
                if (status === 'OK') {
                    console.log(results[0].formatted_address);
                    this.address = results[0].formatted_address;

                    this.console.log(this.address);
                }
            })
        })
    }
```

My view which returns `null`

```
<span>{{address | async}}</span>
```

How can I make this to work?

Comment: Why is this quote not closed? `...('mycolection).d...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code suggests that your address is a formatted string, so `this.address` will have a formatted string when you do:

```
this.address = results[0].formatted_address;
```

To display the same, you wouldn't need `async` pipe, you just have to do:

```
<span>{{address}}</span>
```

`async` pipe is needed when you use an `Observable` and want to use it directly in template.

Also, you cannot use a callback function and expect the value of `this` as the parent class, it will change to the callback functions call-stack. Use a fat arrow function `(results, status) => {...}` instead of normal `function(){}` to retain the value of `this`.

```
    return this.mapsAPILoader.load().then(() => {
        let latlng = new google.maps.LatLng({ lat: coords.latitude, lng: coords.longitude });
        new google.maps.Geocoder().geocode({ 'location': latlng }, (results, status) => {
            console.log(status);
            if (status === 'OK') {
                console.log(results[0].formatted_address);
                this.address = results[0].formatted_address;

                this.console.log(this.address);
            }
        })
    })
```

Comment: Can you add a sample value of `formatted_address` that gets logged in console?

Comment: `10B Bridge St, Westminster, London SW1A 2JR, UK` this is sample the issue its loaded after all other data has already loaded and the view does not watch for changes.

Comment: Check the updated answer. Try using arrow function for callback. Or save a reference to `this` and use it.